# ProJNA Data type mapping

Tags: java, jna

Question below has been modified to narrow down the issue,

I am trying to use a native dll from Java using JNA. I am new to both Java and JNA. For a specific call to one of the dll exported functions, it returns invalid parameters.

Here are the structs ,

PDU_RSC_DATA is a struct which references another struct PDU_PIN_DATA,

```
typedef struct {
UNUM32 BusTypeId; 
UNUM32 ProtocolId;
UNUM32 NumPinData;
PDU_PIN_DATA *pDLCPinData;
} PDU_RSC_DATA;
```

This is how the PDU_PIN_DATA struct looks,

```
typedef struct {
UNUM32 DLCPinNumber; 
UNUM32 DLCPinTypeId; 
} PDU_PIN_DATA;
```

Corresponding JNA Mapping,

```
public class PDU_RSC_DATA extends Structure{ 

public int BusTypeId; 
public int ProtocolId; 
public int NumPinData; 
public Pointer pDLCPinData; 

}

public class PDU_PIN_DATA extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference{

public int DLCPinNumber;
public int DLCPinTypeId;

public PDU_PIN_DATA(){

}

public PDU_PIN_DATA(Pointer ptr_PDU_PIN_DATA) {
    super(ptr_PDU_PIN_DATA);
    read();
}

}
```

Native method -> Modified for easy readability,

```
int _methodXYZ(PDU_RSC_DATA* obj);
```

Java Invocation -> showing only required snippet,

```
PDU_RSC_DATA obj = new PDU_RSC_DATA();
_methodXYZ(obj);
```

Please let me know if the above mapping of struct* within the struct is correct. From the DLL log I notice that the **PDU_PIN_DATA pDLCPinData** is having an invalid value.

Comment: Does the field have an invalid pointer value, or are fields within the PDU_PIN_DATA structure have invalid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL specification was incorrect. **PDU_PIN_DATA *pDLCPinData** was a pointer to arrays of structs instead of pointer to struct. thats why technomage's suggestion din work. Its an issue from my end. **Thanks again technomage.**

Here is how I assign values to the struct array and it works fine. I have modified the PDU_RSC_DATA structure in the question as well.

```
    PDU_RSC_DATA pRscData = new PDU_RSC_DATA();
    pRscData.BusTypeId = 1;
    pRscData.ProtocolId = 7;
    pRscData.NumPinData = 2; 

    PDU_PIN_DATA pDLCPinData = new PDU_PIN_DATA();

    PDU_PIN_DATA[] pDLCPinDataArray= (PDU_PIN_DATA[])pDLCPinData.toArray(pRscData.NumPinData);

    pDLCPinDataArray[0].DLCPinNumber = 6;
    pDLCPinDataArray[0].DLCPinTypeId = 1;
    pDLCPinDataArray[1].DLCPinNumber = 14;
    pDLCPinDataArray[1].DLCPinTypeId = 2;

    pDLCPinData.autoWrite();

    Pointer ptr_pDLCPinData = pDLCPinData.getPointer();
    pRscData.pDLCPinData = ptr_pDLCPinData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NativeLong` (or `int` on Windows) for the native `long` type.  Java `long` is 64-bits which  is most assuredly *not* what you want.

**EDIT**
JNA uses structure pointers by default for function arguments, and structures by value by default within a structure.  In order to get the complementary behavior, use `Structure.ByValue` and `Structure.ByReference` respectively.

If your structure field is a pointer, use a version of your structure which implements `Structure.ByReference`.  JNA will usually automatically handle synching the native memory to the java fields before and after the native call.

Comment: Thanks for the response **technomage**. I used int for the unsigned value of 0XFFFFFFFE and it worked as per the DLL log which I could access. Could you please tell me if the mapping for the struct* within the struct is correct ?

Comment: The above question has been modified to focus on the struct* within struct issue.

Comment: Thanks Technomage, I am having an invalid pointer value for the PDU_PIN_DATA *pDLCPinData field eventhough I am using Structure.ByReference. Is the way I am using this correct ?

Comment: Are you initializing the pointer?  If not, you'll be most likely passing in a NULL value.

Comment: I initialized it like, PDU_PIN_DATA pDLCPinData = new PDU_PIN_DATA(); but I still have the same issue.